# Entering input as sin instead of Np.sin() in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math, pyqt5

I am creating a pyqt5 application to plot a mathematical graph based on the input function.

I am using NumPy for all the mathematical functions.

My question is how can I tweak my code so that I do not need to enter np. whenever I enter sin, cos or tan?

[image: link]

[This is my code getting the user input and plot the graph based on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNcfi.jpg)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (NavigationToolbar2QT  as  NavigationToolbar)

import numpy  as  np

import random


class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        loadUi("qt_designer.ui", self)

        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 & Matplotlib Example GUI")

        self.pushButton_plot.clicked.connect(self.update_graph)
        self.pushButton_discrete.clicked.connect(self.discrete_graph)

        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.MplWidget.canvas, self))


    def update_graph(self):

        x = np.linspace(-10, 10)
        b = self.lineEdit.text()
        c = eval(b)
        y = c

        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()

        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.plot(x, y)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.legend(('cosinus', 'sinus'), loc='upper right')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.set_title(' Cosinus - Sinus Signal')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.draw()

    def discrete_graph(self):
        x = np.linspace(-10, 10)
        b = self.lineEdit.text()
        c = eval(b)
        y = c

        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.clear()

        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.stem(x, y)
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.legend(('cosinus', 'sinus'), loc='upper right')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.axes.set_title(' Cosinus - Sinus Signal')
        self.MplWidget.canvas.draw()


app = QApplication([])
window = MatplotlibWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
enter code here
```

Comment: please improve the formatting of the question and provide full code if possible

Comment: Does `from numpy import sin` work?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid typing "np." everytime before using a specific function, you may just import the functions you wish to use directly. For example:

```
from numpy import sin, cos, tan
```

in order to use these three functions. Now you can simply write:

```
y = sin(3)
```

Comment: I need NumPy to plot graph as well so I still need to import everything.

Comment: In that case you can write " from numpy import * ". It'll load all functions in the local namespace

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion work for me!